# Why eth0 is renamed to enx78e7d1ea46da after upgrade?

Tags: linux, networking, udev

I think this is related to Predictable Network Interface Names. The device is a Raspberry Pi B model running kali (kali-next)

1. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board devices (example: eno1)
2. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: ens1)
3. Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0)
4. Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example: enx78e7d1ea46da)
5. Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: eth0)

Policy 4) is not used by default, but is available if the user chooses it.

Where can I disable policy 4? I don't know why it's enabled in first place. It appears that the firmware/BIOS did not provide index/location information for the Ethernet interface.

```
$ udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/enx78e7d1ea46da 2> /dev/null
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx78e7d1ea46da
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Raspberry Pi Foundation
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is apparently caused by a bug in /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules in versions prior to v233 of the debian and ubuntu udev packages.

The issue was fixed by this commit:

https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-systemd/systemd.git/commit/debian/extra/rules/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules?id=9e202a329175b0ca4eaa09a75897aa2044eb7d7a

See also:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/811295/73-usb-net-by-mac-rules-issue-with-net-ifnames/895879#895879

At the time of writing this v233 has *not* been released for Debian jessie.

One way to fix the issue locally is to edit the file in the same manner as the commit above, then reboot.

Comment: The debian link is broken

Answer (score 0):

```
rm /lib/systemd/network/90-mac-for-usb.link
ln -s /dev/null /lib/systemd/network/90-mac-for-usb.link
```

Comment: Can you explain how this relates to what was asked in the question and what it does?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging and getting nowhere, I found a fix for a Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled server armhf. Long story short, running `$ apt-get update` added [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).

Edit the following file:

```
$ vim /lib/udev/rules/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules
```

You should see:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", NAME=="", \
    ATTR{address}=="?[014589cd]:*", \
    TEST!="/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules", \
    IMPORT{builtin}="net_id", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_MAC}"
```

Change the NAME at the end as follows:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", NAME=="", \
    ATTR{address}=="?[014589cd]:*", \
    TEST!="/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules", \
    IMPORT{builtin}="net_id", NAME="eth0"
```

Save changes. Reboot. Everything should be working now assuming everything is pointing to eth0.